# Classcastexception issue when Migrating Eclipselink ,Spring

Tags: spring, eclipselink

I have working copy of my application in Struts2.0.14, Spring 3.0.0M1, Spring Security 3.0.0M2,Eclipselink  1.1.2,

Now i'm trying to upgrate this to latest version of frameworks so i put Struts 2.3.4, Spring 3.1.2, Spring security 3.1.1 , Eclipselink 2.4.0 jar files.

Now when i running the program , it gives,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourcePlatform
```

here is the sessions.mxl file

```
 <!-- server security -->
 <session xsi:type="server-session">
  <name>dbsession_new</name>
  <event-listener-classes/>
  <logging xsi:type="toplink-log"/>
  <login xsi:type="database-login">
     <platform-class>org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform</platform-class>         
     <user-name>TEMPDB</user-name>
     <password>TEMPPWD</password>
     <sequencing>
        <default-sequence xsi:type="native-sequence">
           <name>Native</name>
        </default-sequence>
     </sequencing>
     <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
     <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@11.101.102.42:1521:ORCL</connection-url>
  </login>
  <connection-pools>
     <read-connection-pool>
        <name>ReadConnectionPool</name>
     </read-connection-pool>
     <write-connection-pool>
        <name>default</name>
     </write-connection-pool>
  </connection-pools>
  <connection-policy/>
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  
    <persistence-unit name="healthPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>       
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.sessions-xml" value="META-INF/sessions.xml"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.session-name" value="dbsession_new"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Spring security Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">     

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/deniedAccess.jsp">
        <intercept-url pattern="/source/admin/**" access="ROLE_PowerUser" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/login.action" access=". . .
        <form-login   . . . 
        <logout logout-success-url=". . . 
        <remember-me key="myAppKey"  data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
           <password-encoder hash="sha-256" base64="true"/>
           <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=" . . .  authorities-by-username-query=" . . .     />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy">
        <filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="sif"/>
        </filter-chain-map>
    </beans:bean> 
    <beans:bean id="sif" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />
</beans:beans>
```

ApplicationContext xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="healthPU"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">FINEST</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.ddl-generation">create-tables</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.cache.type.default">HardWeak</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.cache.size.default">5000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loadTimeWeaver" class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="vendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!--IOC Action Mapings beans start--> 
<!-- Action Mapings beans end --> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Sounds like a classloader issue. Where are you putting the jars and have you checked there aren't any other copies either in your server or application libraries? I would take things a small step at a time in changing from your working app, rather than trying to do everything at once. That way you can work out at what point the error occurs.

Comment: followed the same, first i upgraded eclipselink jars alone with current combination- it works, then in next step i tried to update Spring-security- that inter needs Spring-core update, so i have upgraded both. now the same classcastexception occurs. look like some problem in spring that handles jpa differently, or i may be need some extra listener or something

Comment: added applicationContext and applicationContext-security files

Comment: I don't thinl the application context files will be the problem. Please post the list of jars that are in your WEB-INF/lib and any you have added to your server's library directories. Make sure there are no duplicates or different versions.